# Change queryset in ModelViewSet in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I wrote a RegistrationView for Djoser

```
class RegistrationView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserRegistrationSerializer

    permission_classes = (
        permissions.AllowAny,
    )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = serializer.save()
        signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__, user=user, request=self.request)
        if settings.get('SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL'):
            self.send_activation_email(user)
        elif settings.get('SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL'):
            self.send_confirmation_email(user)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        token = create_token(serializer.data)
        return Response(data=token, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def send_activation_email(self, user):
        email_factory = utils.UserActivationEmailFactory.from_request(self.request, user=user)
        email = email_factory.create()
        email.send()

    def send_confirmation_email(self, user):
        email_factory = utils.UserConfirmationEmailFactory.from_request(self.request, user=user)
        email = email_factory.create()
        email.send()
```

As you can see, I want to use my own `create` function. That's why I use a ModelViewSet

But as you can see, I declare the queryset in a way where all the user objects will be listed, and I don't really like it.

So, my question.

Is there a way to declare another "queryset" that doesn't show that information?

Or should I write my "create" function in another place and don't write the queryset there?  The point is that I want to call the create function in the registration process.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why don't you **none** the queryset if don't want to list all users.

```
queryset = User.objects.none()
```

Or you can override get_queryset method also.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(RegistrationView, self).get_queryset()
    qs = qs.none()
    return qs
```

Comment: Because I'm stupid and I didn't know there's a "none()" method. hehe Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't need `ModelViewSet` at all. It allows to easily implement CRUD operations, but in your case, as far as I'm concerned, you'll only need endpoint responsible for creating user. You should take a look at  [`CreateApiView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview).